# find the first occurrence of Sunday from a given date

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want to find the date of the first occurrence of a Sunday before a given date.

e.g. I have a method that excepts current date and lets say the date is today's date Tuesday 02-09-2014 and the method will return the date of the past Sunday 31-08-2014.

Is there any way that I can get it done in Java??

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#dayOfWeek()

Comment: This got an upvote? How exactly is it that this question "_shows research effort_"?

Answer (score 1):

With java 8 you can use one of the built-in [TemporalAdjusters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html):

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate previousSunday = today.with(previous(SUNDAY));
//or if today is a Sunday and you want to return today:
LocalDate previousSunday = today.with(previousOrSame(SUNDAY));
```

<sub>note: assumes static imports:

`import static java.time.DayOfWeek.SUNDAY;`

`import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.previous;`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1));
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int diff = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - Calendar.SUNDAY;
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -diff);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `java.util.Calendar`

Substract the difference (in days) between sunday and now:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = c.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK );
c.add( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY - day);
```

And you got it.